# Why are unquoted numbers in JSON coming across as undefined?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a node.js service running that is persisting data to mongodb via mongoosejs. My schema for my collection has two fields one named "source_id" that is defined as a Number and one named "name" that is defined as a String.  When I persist the data to Mongo it looks like this within Mongo.

```
{"source_id": 1234, "name": "Test Name"}
```

I can retrieve this data via mongoose without issue, but when I try to access the source_id field it comes across as undefined.  I can access "name" without issue.  If I intercept the JSON that is returned and put quotes around the 1234 it works without issue.

Should all fields in a mongo collection be treated as string and quoted regardless of datatype?  If so how can I make mongoose put double quotes around it when it is defined as a Number in the schema?  Or am I doing something else wrong here and the unquoted value is fine for number fields?

Comment: I suspect that something else is going on.  Can you post your schema and how you are retrieve the document and then accessing the `source_id`?

Comment: Can you console.log(theDataFromMongo) to see if that is really there? It is not about JSON related, it works if you type var a = {"source_id": 1234, "name": "Test Name"}; and you can access a.source_id and a.name